# Apache SetEnv prepends REDIRECT_ . What gives?

Tags: php, apache, setenv

For an application based on Zend Framework I use apaches `SetEnv` in `.htaccess`. I use this on test, staging and production servers like so:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT production
```

On the staging server I couldn't read this env var in PHP. However when I did a `var_dump( $_ENV )` in php I got the value but the key was prepended with `REDIRECT_` becoming

```
REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening, and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing you have mod_rewrite rules in your .htaccess as well for Zend?  I believe it may be mod_rewrite prepending that when it does a redirect so that the value won't be overridden by any new settings with the new URL.

Comment: You guessed correct indeed. You might be right about mod_rewrite, but I don't believe the other servers show this behaviour too, and they have the exact same mod_rewrite setup. I'll have to check it out. Thanks so far.

Comment: @fireeyedboy I was actually surprised to find very little about this issue at all other than user comments in forum posts and no actual reliable source information.  I did see one or two posts about it being Apache version specific, is your staging machine's Apache a different version than your dev and production?  Are your dev and production the same and it's not doing it on either of those?

Comment: @fireeyedboy can you elaborate – did you do something to solve this?

Comment: @CharlieS I use the following to define the constant in my index.php file: `defined( 'APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' ) || define( 'APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT', getenv( 'APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' ) ? getenv( 'APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' ) : ( getenv( 'REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' ) ? getenv( 'REDIRECT_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' ) : 'production' ) );` (defaulting to 'production' if it cannot find the environment variable)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was because of was running PHP as cgi in my Apache.

After enabling mod_php, I could access to my variable without that prefix.