# Problems using client certificate authentication in PHP (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, ssl, x509certificate

I am doing certificate based client access control. I'm letting Apache ensure that the certificate is good, then matching it to a user in our database. The problem I'm having is that all of the fields Apache is inserting into `$_SERVER[]` are coming up `REDIRECT_SSL_*` instead of `SSL_*`.

I'm getting:

```
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN     =  CAcert WoT User
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email  =  name@example.com
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_O      =  Root CA
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_OU     =  http://www.cacert.org
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN     =  CA Cert Signing Authority
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_Email  =  support@cacert.org
REDIRECT_SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY      =  SUCCESS
...
```

where all the documentation I've read suggests I should be getting:

```
SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN     =  CAcert WoT User
SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email  =  name@example.com
SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_O      =  Root CA
SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_OU     =  http://www.cacert.org
SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN     =  CA Cert Signing Authority
SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_Email  =  support@cacert.org
SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY      =  SUCCESS
...
```

Why is it coming up differently?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267976/apache-setenv-appends-redirect-what-gives

Comment: Thanks Sean, now go answer so I can accept :)